# Can't find error with my code for sort 0 1 2? Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Could you please tell me what is the issue with my code? I am getting segmentation fault for this specific input (and more) but for few it running fine?
What is it that I am missing?

```
void sortArr(int a[], int n)
{
    int x,y;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==0)
        {
            x++;
        }
        else if(a[i]==1)
        {
            y++;
        }
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=x;i<(x+y);i++)
    {
        a[i]=1;
    }
    for(i=(x+y);i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=2;
    }
    // Print the sorted array
    printArr(a, n);
}

 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0,2,1,2,0,2,2,0,0,1};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
 
    sortArr(arr, n);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variables must be initialized before you use them, e.g. `int x=0, y=0;`

Comment: It's only bad luck that it seems to work sometimes - your code has undefined behaviour because of the problem pointed out by @user3386109.

Comment: Also, it's a very specific sort: works only for values 0 through 2.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your variables before using them:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
```

If you don't initialize the variables, then they will have indeterminate values which may lead to undefined behavior, and in some cases, this can also cause errors. (For example with MSVC)